# Edit TextView column on ListView WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm Using WPF.
I have ListView with TextBox column and two checkboxs columns.

I want to edit the TextBox text by double click or something else.
What is the simple way to do that?

```
...
<GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding={Binding Path=fullName}" Width=500>
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                      <TextBox Name="txtName"/>
               </DataTemplate>
         </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
...
```

Comment: @Edd thats isn't talking about textbox inside Listview

Comment: I removed the "flag"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample way of doing this...

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Items = new List<string>();
        LoadItems();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void txtName_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox currentTextBox = (TextBox)sender;
        if (currentTextBox.IsReadOnly)
            currentTextBox.IsReadOnly = false;
        else
            currentTextBox.IsReadOnly = true;
    }

    private void LoadItems()
    {
        Items.Add("Coffee");
        Items.Add("Sugar");
        Items.Add("Cream");
    }
}

<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Name="txtName" Text="{Binding Mode=OneTime}" IsReadOnly="True" MouseDoubleClick="txtName_MouseDoubleClick" Width="100"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>                    
            </GridView>                
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hi, i try to do that but that isn't worked. i can't click on the column, when i click on the textbox column thats select all the row and the callback isnt called

Comment: This does work. You might be missing it. Start the app and try and type in the first textbox. NO DICE! Now double click it! Type away... Now double click it again. Now try and type. Locked!

Comment: I made changes to the code above for completeness and testing. It is now a complete working example. Make sure to debug and set a breakpoint in the DoubleClick event handler.

Comment: If you are just trying to plug this into existing code I don't have that tested, but the above code does work if you create a new WPF app from scratch and try it.

Comment: Hi @Edd, thank you very much. its work for empty and new project. in my project the ListView in binding to class, you have idea why i dont get the callback? thank you very much!

Comment: Is it possible to see the code for the UI Element and the Code Behind? That would have me answer you question better. You can just edit you original post and add it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I have from an application that I wrote. The column JobName was to be user editable.  This example allows the column to be editable and also gets rid of the border and lets the background blend into the row so it doesn't appear to have a text box in it.
Those can be edited out `(BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent")`.

My example binds to an MVVM ViewModel property called JobName and is set to be "TwoWay" so that changes to the view model will also reflect on the UI.

```
 <ListView x:Name="lvJobs" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="628" Margin="30,62,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Jobs}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedJob, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="335">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Active" Width="50">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsActive, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Job Name" Width="150">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding JobName, Mode=TwoWay}" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding User}" Header="User" Width="125"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```